# Reference DLLs from subfolder of a NuGet package with PackageReference

Tags: .net, nuget, packagereference

We are upgrading a project from packages.config to the PackageReference structure. One of the packages referenced has DLLs in subfolders like:

- lib\net45\some.dll
- lib\net45\xxx\other.dll

When referencing this package from a project using packages.config all the DLLs of the package are included as references in the project and it works fine. When using PackageReference it seems to only recognize the DLLs in the root folder (lib\net45). We get build errors for everything using functionality from DLLs in the subfolders. Is there a way to tell NuGet to consider the subfolders of a NuGet package when using PackageReference?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Running into the same issue :/

Comment: No, I reverted to packages.config for that project :-(